# Pause and resume Observable Stream and only emit custom messages from other stream during that pause with RxJS

Tags: rxjs

I have a hot observable emitting messages continuously. I need to pause it with an API REST endpoint like an actuator `/messages/pause`, and resume it with other API REST endpoint like `/messages/resume`. During the pause time I need to allow with other API REST endpoint to emit a message like the original observable `/messages/custom`.

It is possible to pause the main observable stream during that interval (pause-resume) but not stop observing the mocked messages events, and continue/restore the main observable stream after resume it?

Comment: By *pausing*, you mean to ignore its events, right? I don't it would be very feasible to actually pause the Observable since you can't really control the source.

Comment: Yes, pause of receiving events or messages (or ignore them during the pause time), but only receive the second custom stream messages.

Comment: By *second custom stream*, you mean another Observable, right?

Comment: Yes, with the same characteristics and objects to emit, like mocked objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be an approach:

```js
// The 2 sources of events.
const main$ = /* ... */;
const second$ = /* ... */;

// Emits when the `/pause` endpoint is reached.
// `pause.next(true);`
// When the `/resume` endpoint is reached: `pause.next(false)`
const pause = new Subject<boolean>();

const decoratedMain$ = main$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(paused.pipe(startWith(false))),
  filter(([mainValue, isPaused]) => !isPaused),
  map(([mainValue]) => mainValue),
);

const decoratedSecond$ = second$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(paused),
  filter(([secondValue, isPaused]) => isPaused),
  map(([secondValue]) => secondValue),
);

merge(decoratedMain$, decoratedSecond$).subscribe();
```

---

The above snippet, unless I've missed something, should implement this logic:

- while the `main$` observable emits, the `second$` observable's events won't be taken into consideration
- `main$` can be paused(with `pause.next(true)`) and resumed(with `pause.next(false)`)
- when `main$` is paused, its events are ignored and the `second$` observable's events are now considered
- when `main$` is resumed, the *switch* takes place again: `second$`'s events are ignored and `main$`'s events are considered

Let's now see what part of RxJS' magic has been used to achieve this.

As you may have noticed, the main logic revolves around `withLatestFrom` and the `pause` Subject.

The `decoratedMain$` observable keeps on emitting, but whether its events are ignored or not depends on the latest value of `pause`. If the `/pause` endpoint is reached, then the events will be ignored, since `pause` would have emitted `true`.

The `decoratedSecond$` is built symmetrically. Its events are ignored if the latest value of `pause` is `false`.

---

Lastly, I thought it would be helpful to share a small variation of the above approach, just for learning purposes:

```js
/* ... */
const isMainPaused$ = pause.pipe(filter(Boolean));
const isMainResumed$ = pause.pipe(filter(v => !v));

const decoratedMain$ = main$.pipe(
  share({ resetOnRefCountZero: false }),
  takeUntil(isMainPaused$),
  repeatWhen(completionsSubject => completionsSubject.pipe(mergeMapTo(isMainResumed$)))
);

/* ... */
```

The rest of the code is the same as in the first approach. Here, what's going on is essentially ignoring the `main$`'s events by not having any subscriber to the `share`'s `Subject` instance. When `pause` emits `false`, a new subscriber is created for that `Subject` instance, without re-subscribing to the source and that's due to the `resetOnRefCountZero: false` option.

Comment: Just I was looking for. Very detailed explanation and combination of observable operators. I was trying mainly with those operators but I didn't use `withLatestFrom`.